# How to make UML diagram for USER-ROLE with a Organisation

Tags: uml, domain-model

I'm new in UML representation. I couldn't map a UML representaion for below representation

```
1. Company have many users.

2. Each user may belongs to different company.

3.Each user may have different roles in different company.
```

If I have represent a UML diagram for this,how can we find the roles of a user in each company.

Comment: This is not clear. Which UML diagram are you talking about? Class diagram? If so, is it a design class diagram or an analysis class diagram? What do you mean by finding the role of a user in a company?

Comment: I'M LOOKING FOR CLASS DIAGRAM. I MEAN FROM THE CLASS DIAGRAM HOW CAN WE IDENTIFY THE ROLES OF EACH USER IN A COMPANY

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Information we get from this diagram:

1- A company can have many roles: manager, programmer are roles in company a

2- Every role belongs to one company.

3- A user may have many roles: be a consultant at company a and programmer at company b.

4- A role may be overtaken by many users: user 1 and 2 are both programmers at company a

What this diagram shows is the static structure, you cannot identify which specific user works for which specific company using a class diagram.

You can use an object diagram for that purpose, but an object diagram is useful for showing just a snap shot of the system with specific instances.